# Transpose n' rows to one single column

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I want to transpose three rows into a single column. For example:

```
    A     B      C       D       E       F       G
1 60000 40000   50000   40000   50000   50000   40000
2 50000 40000   50000   50000   40000   50000   50000
3 60000 50000   50000   50000   50000   50000   50000
```

.

```
 A
60000 1
40000 1
50000 1
40000 1
50000 1
50000 1
40000 1
50000 2
40000 2
50000 2
50000 2
40000 2
50000 2
50000 2
60000 3
50000 3
50000 3
50000 3
50000 3
50000 3
50000 3
```

I wrote VBA and ended up with code that wasn't automated enough. My logic is for each column transpose:true then concatenate them in a single column.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.  We can help figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/7,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,7))
```

and then copy downwards.

[image]

Using similar formulas, you can map any rectangular table into a single column or a single row.  It is also possible to map any single row or column into a rectangular table.

**EDIT#1:**

To get the **second** column in the Poster's example, pick the cell adjacent to my single column output and enter:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/7,0)
```

and copy downwards. *(in my example this is cell  **I5** )*

Comment: @pnuts See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @pnuts  I used to use *ROW()* for this kind of application, but I am now using *ROWS()* because it makes the series formula **independent** of the position of the starting cell!!

Comment: @p **OUCH!!**  *I fixed it.*